# Oracle BPEL Schema Validation - Where does it look for schema definitions

Tags: oracle, xsd, oracle11g, middleware, bpel

I have a BPEL application in 11g with the *schema-validate-input* property of the binding set to true.  When I send a request to this application I get the error:

`Input Violates Schema : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element`

What this tells me is that it is unable to locate the xsd for the message schema.

1. Where does BPEL search for these schema definitions and
2. how do the necessary schemas get loaded into the environment?

I am using Oracle Fusion Middleware 11.1.1.5.0 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's able to find your schema,but couldn't find the declaration of element.
Every BPEL process has a WSDL and within this WSDL, you will find either inline schema or schema's imported from another file.

So, check your BPEL process WSDL for schemas used.

Comment: In this instance the wsdl does import the necessary schemas and loading of the schema locations from the urls provided in the wsdl correctly finds the schemas manually.  The namespaces are correct as far as I can tell with a manual check and I cannot see why it is unable to find it.